# Не отрабатывает тег шаблона {% url 'login' %} в Django

Tags: django

Ребята, поскажите, что может быть не так с кодом.

В шаблоне главной страницы base.html делаю ссылку на авторизацию с помощью тега шаблона, все по туториалу:

```
<a href="{% url 'login' %}">Войти</a>
<a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Выйти</a>
```

В urls.py импортирую готовые вьюшки авторизации и ссылаюсь на них:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', views.login),
    url(r'^accounts/logout/$', views.logout, name='logout', kwargs={'next_page': '/'}),
]
```

В папке templates создаю папку registration, в ней login.html. Опять же, по оф. документации. В нем делаю форму авторизации:

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    {% if form.errors %}
        <p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
    {% endif %}

    <form method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ form.username.label_tag }}</td>
            <td>{{ form.username }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ form.password.label_tag }}</td>
            <td>{{ form.password }}</td>
        </tr>
        </table>

        <input type="submit" value="login" />
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Замучала ошибка:

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'login' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Зато если меняю этот тег шаблона {% url 'login' %} на обычную ссылку:

```
<a href="accounts/login/">Войти</a>
```

то все отрабатывает хорошо. И ссылка работает и логинится нормально со странички login.html. Не могу понять почему ему не нравится {% url 'login' %}. Что я упускаю?

Рядом прописан такой же почти logout. Он работает как надо. В чем разница?

Comment: А на этой странице `accounts/login/` все нормально логинится, Вы можете войти?

Answer (score 2):

Перепишите файл urls.py, вот верно:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^accounts/logout/$', views.logout, name='logout', kwargs={'next_page': '/'}),
]
```

Django не понимает какую ссылку вставлять. Вы не прописали имя для ссылки `accounts/login/` - `name='login'`.

Comment: хмм, действительно, мог бы заметить разницу с logout) плюсом понял для чего эти неймы прописываются, спасибо за помощь)

Comment: @dnlv так а проблема решена? Ошибку уже не кидает?